CSV files showing different date formats in a single column
I'm receiving CSV files from a vendor, and these files contain date columns with various formats. When I open the CSV files on the server using vi filename.csv, I notice that a single date column can have different formats:
2022-07-26T05:00:00
2022-07-12T05:00:00.000z
2020-06-29T13:58:27.000+00
2021-11-26 05:00:00
2020-06-10

This variation in date formats is causing issues when trying to load the data into an Oracle table using SQL Loader and a control file.
Could anyone help me understand how to handle these different date formats during the loading process?
I have tried using different date formats, but it hasn't worked for me.

You can use a SQL expression in your control file that uses CASE or DECODE and tests for various formats and uses the appropriate TO_DATE function for each. Or you can load it into a table as a string, then use SQL logic, or even a view, in post-processing to convert it in the next step.
